# Multiple kestrel stateless service instances running on different ports in service fabric

Tags: c#, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have created a Stateless service in Visual Studio 2019 using the sample defaults (Create new project -> Service Fabric Application -> name the project and solution -> Stateless ASP.NET Core service).

Running the weather forecast application with no changes works fine, I can see the application running in the Service Fabric explorer and see my 5 healthy (local development) nodes and 1 green application.

If I modify `Local.5Node.xml` to change the InstanceCount from 1 to -1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/SampleApp" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="SampleApp_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="Development" />
    <Parameter Name="SampleApp_InstanceCount" Value="-1" />
  </Parameters>
</Application>
```

I can see under the single partition five instances get created, yet four of them are stuck in 'InBuild':
[image]

And in my running application in VS2019 the Diagnostics window shows processes continually failing to startup:

[image]

Upon further inspection, I see that the new instances are trying to be spun up on the same port.

[image]

**How does port assignment work in Service Fabric with multiple instances of stateless web services?** Does it require a gateway with a reverse proxy to discover each instance? Is autoscaling a stateless web service possible in Service Fabric without custom solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kestrel doesn't support port sharing, so as soon as one service claims the port, others running on the same machine (here: your dev machine) cannot.

The simplest workaround, is to create **1** instance of your service when running on your dev cluster. Another way to work around this, is to use (random) SF assigned ports locally:

> Omit the Endpoint configuration in `ServiceManifest.xml` entirely, and
>   don't pass an endpoint name to the `KestrelCommunicationListener`
>   constructor

Next, use a (e.g. the [built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy)) reverse proxy to communicate with your services.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#kestrel-in-reliable-services)